# Сгенерировать подпись строки (sha1WithRSAEncryption) длиной 512 и закодировать в base64

Tags: node.js

```js
const rawSignature = crypto.createSign('sha1WithRSAEncryption')
rawSignature.update(data)
const signature = rawSignature.sign(privateKey,'base64')
```

Я ожидаю длину подписи `512`, а длину base64 `684`. Как мне изменить длину

Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я просто сгенерировал заново пару ключей, но с длиной 4096, и теперь подпись длиной 512 и 684 в виде base64